# Measurability of intersection map with respect to Hausdorff metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, and let $\mathcal{K}(X)$ denote the set of compact subsets of $X$. We endow $\mathcal{K}(X)$ with the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). Fix a compact subset $K\subset \in \mathcal{K}(X)$ and consider the map
$$f_K: \mathcal{K}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{K}(X), \qquad f_K(A) := A\cap K$$
We can turn $\mathcal{K}(X)$ into a measurable space by endowing it with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K}(X))$.

> **Question.** Is the map
>   $$f_K: (\mathcal{K}(X), \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K}(X))) \rightarrow (\mathcal{K}(X), \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K}(X)))$$
>   measurable?

Comment: Isn't it continuous and thus measurable?

Comment: Normally $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{K}(X)$. Do you allow it? Your link defines the Hausdorff metric explictly for *non-empty* sets too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I realize this issue. It should be non-empty subsets, otherwise the hausdorff distance may be infinite. This leads to another issue which the map I defined does not necessarily map to the non-empty compact subsets.

Comment: True, if $x\notin K$ then $A=\{x\}$ is an easy point that $f_K$ is not defined on, etc. I've seen treatments of hyperspaces that allow $\emptyset$ as an element but it is then an isolated point, e.g. we could define $d(\emptyset,K)=1$ for non-empty $K$. (or $+\infty$). This "kills" nice theorems like $\mathcal{K}()X)$ is connected when $X$ is connected, but keeps compactness of it for compact $X$.